# Continuity of the partial derivatives of this function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Consider
$$f(x, y) = \frac{x^3 - xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$
otherwise it's $0$ at the origin.

I have to show if the partial derivatives are continuous.

So first of all: continuity of the function at the origin:

$$\bigg|\frac{x^3 - xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\bigg| = |x| \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq |x|\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq |x| + |y| \to (0) \quad \text{as}\quad $(x, y) \to 0$$

The I shoed the partial derivatives do exist:

$$f'_x(0, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} f(h, 0) = 1$$
$$f'_y(0, 0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} f(0, h) = 0$$

The continuity is instead a bit tough:

$$f'_x(x, y) = \frac{x^4+4 x^2 y^2-y^4}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$

Having to be continuous:

$$\bigg|\frac{x^4+4 x^2 y^2-y^4}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} - 1 \bigg| = \frac{2x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leq \frac{2(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leq 2$$

The same for $f'_y$:

$$f'_y(x, y) = -\frac{4 x^3 y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}$$

hence

$$\bigg| -\frac{4 x^3 y}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\bigg| = \frac{4x^2|x||y|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leq \frac{4(x^2+y^2)(|x| + |y|)(|x| + |y|)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leq \frac{4(x^2+y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leq 4$$

I'm stuck on those two parts for I don't get how to recover a distance which goes to zero.

Answer (score 3):

The partial derivatives are not continuous. Consider limit along $y=x$ and that along $x=0$.

Comment: Oh! I did not think about to check some paths before to jump into the majorization quest... Thank you! 
I'm actually trying to see if it's differentiable, but I got stuck too:

$$\bigg|\frac{f(x, y) - x f'_x(0, 0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\bigg| = \frac{|x|(x^2-y^2-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ 

And then I tried 

$$\leq \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to -1$$

as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$

Comment: Oh wait I wrote a malarkey...

Comment: @Numb3rs It is not differentiable. Consider limit along $x=0$ and $y=x$.

Comment: Lol, again I jumpet into the quest without checking paths.. Thank you!!